# How to call a .exe from PL/SQL?

Tags: windows, oracle, plsql, cmd

I have given the following grants for permission and calling `CMD.EXE` appears to work like shown in below code example.

However, I cannot get any output from `whoami.exe`. I can see that the default directory is `C:\app\oramgr\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\database\` that appears in the `JJJ.TXT` file. However, the `JJJ_WHOAMI.TXT` file contains nothing.

Any suggestions?

```
dbms_java.grant_permission('PWATSON', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CMD.EXE', 'execute');
dbms_java.grant_permission('PWATSON', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', 'C:\Windows\System32\whoami.exe', 'execute');
dbms_java.grant_permission('PWATSON', 'SYS:java.lang.RuntimePermission', '*', 'writeFileDescriptor');
dbms_java.grant_permission('PWATSON', 'SYS:java.lang.RuntimePermission', '*', 'readFileDescriptor');

dbms_java.grant_permission('PWATSON', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', 'C:\Users\pwatson', 'read, write');
dbms_java.grant_permission('PWATSON', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', 'C:\Users\pwatson\*', 'read, write');
dbms_java.grant_permission('PWATSON', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', 'C:\temp', 'read');

SQL> select util.RUN_CMD('C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.EXE /c CD C:\Users\pwatson\src\java ^& ECHO ^%CD^% ^& EXIT 4') as y from dual;
         Y
----------
         4

C:\app\oramgr\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\DATABASE
SQL> select util.RUN_CMD('C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.EXE /c ECHO ^%CD^% >jjj.txt ^& EXIT 7') as y from dual;
         Y
----------
         7

SQL> select util.RUN_CMD('C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.EXE /c C:\Windows\System32\whoami.exe >jjj_whoami.txt') as y from dual;
         Y
----------
         0


C:\app\oramgr\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\database>type JJJ.TXT
C:\app\oramgr\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\DATABASE

C:\app\oramgr\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\database>type JJJ_WHOAMI.TXT
```

Comment: What windows user is running Database server service? To make a test try to run the service with another windows and try to run the sentence again.

Comment: When I saw this before on a PDB it was the 'oracle' user. On the non-PDB install it is 'oramgr'. What do you mean by "another Windows"?

Comment: What windows version you use?

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:150612348067

Comment: Maybe Oracle is a nobody when it runs `whoami` on Windows?

Comment: not sure on windows, but can you try redirecting stderr to stdout, using 2>&1 and end of command?

Comment: Thank you for the additional suggestion. I will get back to it in a week.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Oracle is a nobody when it runs `whoami` on Windows? Good idea is to change the user who starts the service.

---

The third call is slightly different from the second. You didn't call for an exit.

Try the below:

```
select util.RUN_CMD('C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.EXE /c C:\Windows\System32\whoami.exe >jjj_whoami.txt ^& EXIT 8') as y from dual;
```